# Issue with boxColor and SDL_MapRGBA functions in SDL_gfx (c++)

Tags: c++, sdl, uint32

I want to fill the screen with `blue`.

This function works :

```
boxColor(screen, 0, 0, 640, 640, 0x0000ffff);
```

this one doesn't :

```
boxColor(screen, 0, 0, 640, 640, SDL_MapRGBA(screen->format, 0, 0, 255, 255));
```

What am I missing with the second version? How does one use `SDL_MAPRGBA` in this `context`?

Comment: Can you describe exactly what goes wrong? Compiler error, wrong colour, or something else?

Comment: oh, sorry, it just doesn't do anything. More precisely, the first function colors the screen in blue, whereas the second version doesn't have any effect whatsoever (no errors or anything)

Comment: So, the first step would be to figure out what `SDL_MapRGBA()` returns. Print it out as a hex number, perhaps?

Comment: cout << hex << SDL_MapRGBA(screen->format, 0, 0, 255, 255) << endl; outputs "1f" o_O

Comment: Then figure out what `screen->format` actually is, because `1f` doesn't seem right.

Comment: and if i use boxColor(screen, 0, 0, 640, 640, SDL_MapRGBA(screen->format, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff)); , then the screen fills with blue...

Comment: Try printing screen->format->BitsPerPixel

Comment: and, if I put the rgba values in the wrong way round, it works as required : boxColor(screen, 0, 0, 640, 640, SDL_MapRGBA(screen->format, 255, 255, 0, 0));

Comment: ah well, at least it works

Comment: But either the docs is wrong, or something is wrong in your SDL version.